# How to find the control that raised an event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have many custom controls on my main form that utilize an event to signify they have done processing. They all share this same event (~100 controls or so).

The main form consumes this event but I do not have a clue how to find an efficient way at getting to the one that raised the event without having really inefficient code.

My controls are contained within a `List<T>` called `controlList` and are hosted on their own project.

My event looks like so:

```
public void OnTaskComplete(object sender, custom_control_project.TaskCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var control in controlList)
        {
            if (control.Visible) // <--- THIS IS WRONG! WHAT COULD THIS BE???
            {
                try
                {
                    ...// LOTS OF PROCESSING!
                }
                catch
                {
                    ...
                }
                finally
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }        
    }
```

If I want to use less controls, I make them invisible and disabled, hence the `control.Visible`.

How can I make it so I only do work on the one control that raised the event without having to process so much unneeded iterations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sender parameter is the object that raised the event.  You can cast this to a control.

Comment: So easy... Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the all of the controls are wired to the same event (which you indicate):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).Visible = true;

    // or more generally:
    ((WebControl)sender).Visible = true;
}
```

You will need to cast the `sender` to a common, base type. If you go with a base type, `WebControl` will allow you to access the `Enabled` property while `Control` will not.